# Double clicks in NSWindows?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, events, user-interface

NSWindows have a variety of function to handle mouse events (i.e. void mouseDown for a left click, void mouseDragged for drags etc.). What function is used to handle double clicks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSWindow` is a subclass of `NSResponder` and inherits its methods.
Each event handling method, `-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent;` is one of them, takes an parameter; the *event object*.

To find out how many clicks have been recorded, query the event object.

From [`NSEvent`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSEvent) documentation, here is the method that returns such information :

```
-(NSInteger)clickCount;
```

> Returns the number of mouse clicks associated with the receiver, which represents a mouse-down or mouse-up event.